# Em formulários no JS, utilizando a tag <input> no html, pq não posso lincar uma variável no <script> diretamente para a input?

Tags: input

```
<h1>Somando Valores</h1>
    <input type="number" name='txtn1' id="txtn1"> +
    <input type="number" name="txtn2" id="txtn2">
    <input type="button" value="Somar" onclick="somar()">
    <div id="res"> Resultado</div>

function somar() {



    var n1 = Number.parseFloat(window.document.getElementById('txtn1'))
    var n2 = Number.parseFloat(window.document.getElementById('txtn2'))
    var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
    var s = n1 + n2
    res.innerHTML = `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${s}`

      }

    </script>
```

Por que não posso fazer isso? 
Nessa caso teria que abrir uma variável para o `cont`

Comment: Que **cont**? Sua pergunta não está clara!

Comment: Pq não posso fazer isso? Nesse caso teria que abrir uma variável para o conteúdo da <imput> e depois abrir outra variável colocando está variável dentro, assim:

Comment: function somar() {
    var txt1= window.document.getElementById('txtn1')
    var txt2= window.document.getElementById('txtn2')
    var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
    
    var n1 = Number(txt1.value)
    var n2 = Number(txt2.value)
    
    var s = n1 + n2
    res.innerHTML = `A soma entre ${n1} e ${n2} é igual a ${s}`

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com mais detalhes para nós te dar uma resposta mais direta, assim não da para entender o que você quer.